# How to avoid background zero values in erdas imagine model maker?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing, model-maker

Does anyone know how to avoid background black color/ zero value in background pixels in processed images using erdas imagine? Particularly in model maker. It's confusing in statistical calculation.